# Retrieve name or slug from get_objects_in_term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, order

I have taxonomies set up for users, and on `taxonomy-{term}.php` I have the following code to "loop" them all out, sorted by ID:

```
$term_id = get_queried_object_id(); // Get taxonomy term ID
$term = get_queried_object(); // Get the term
$argu = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all'); // Order
$users = get_objects_in_term( $term_id, $term->taxonomy, $argu );

if ( !empty( $users ) ) { // Don't show if empty ?>

<?php foreach ( $users as $user_id ) if (!user_can( $user_id, 'invisible' )) { // Exclude users with the role invisible ?>

<!-- Thumbnail, title, name etc. here -->
```

How would I go about sorting them by their last name (which is a custom field)?
Ideally I would like to change `'orderby' => 'name'` to something like `'orderby' => 'CUSTOM-FIELD-NAME'`, or if I could utilize `get_objects_in_term()->name;` somehow.

Here's a `var_dump($users)` from a term page where I have four users:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(2) "12" [1]=> string(2) "19" [2]=> string(2) "20" [3]=> string(2) "21" }
```

The number inside the quotes is the users' ID.

**Edit, completely revised using WP_User_Query**

```
$args = array(
'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
'role' => 'talare',
'order' => 'DESC',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
    'key' => 'last_name', // the meta field (or key) we want to target for sorting
    )
));
//get_users calls WP_User_Query and returns an array of matching users
$users = get_users($args);

//custom function for comparing the data we want to sort by
function cmp($a, $b){
    if ($a->last_name == $b->last_name) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->last_name > $b->last_name) ? 1 : -1;
}
//usort sorts our $users array with our function cmp()
    usort($users, 'cmp');

//leaving an array of $users sorted by the value of meta 'last_name'
foreach ($users as $user) {
    //Thumbnail, title, name etc.
}
```

[I got the sorting-function from here.](http://buddypress.org/support/topic/list-buddpyress-users-ordered-by-meta_value/)

Comment: Have you tried a `WP_User_Query`?

Comment: I have never setup a user taxonomy. What is `var_dump($users)`?

Comment: @kaiser `WP_User_Query` does actually seem better for this. In my edit you can see my revised code using this. The sorting now works as I want it to, but now all the users are being shown, instead of just those belonging to the taxonomy term.
I've tried using `'meta-key'` but can't seem to get what I want.

Comment: I have to double @s_ha_dum question: What is a user taxonomy? How do you attach a taxonomy to a user?

Comment: @kaiser : apparently [user taxonomies are possible](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress).

Comment: @s_ha_dum If so: How? Additional custom fields for users and then misuse user meta data as taxonomy taxon/term storage? In this case I wouldn't say it's a "user taxonomy", just user meta. An additional table and using the existing meta data API? Please elaborate.

Comment: @kaiser : The link I found to the Justin Tadlock article is the best I've got. I have never done it and there does seem to be a lot of additional work to make it truly functional.

Comment: @kaiser, @s_ha_dum
I have user taxonomies set up (using Tadlocks code) and they are working just fine, what I'm trying to do now is get a list of users who belong to each term. In my OP used `taxonomy-{term}.php` and `get_queried_object` to get only the users associated with that specific term. The only problem then was that I couldn't find a way to sort them by `$user->last_name`. The problem is now reversed: I have all the users and can sort them by `last_name`, but I cant exclude users from other terms.

Comment: @talven : my original question, concerning your original code, was "What is `var_dump($users)`?" Is that a user object?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Yes, through it I get the ID's of the users belonging to the currently viewed term.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Read that article and it sounds valid. Thanks for link. **Ad OP)** What do you get: User IDs, or full user objects? Edit your question with a full example output (like the first three users from the `var_dump()`).

Comment: @s_ha_dum Sorry for not linking to Tadlocks article at first, I guess user taxonomies aren't that common yet? I added your requested edit just above my initial edit.